# Remove activity 2 and 3 from back stack when starting activity 4

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 4 Android activities. Let's call them **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**.

The normal flow is **A => B => C => D**. However, when I enter **D** I want to remove **B** and **C** from the back stack.

Is it solvable?

Note that if the user is in **C** and presses back, **B** should still be displayed!

**Edit:** Starting activity A again with CLEAR_TOP did call onCreate again on Activity A which I do not want. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I recently had the same issue, and couldn't find a solution anywhere.  The only solution I could get to work is a bit of a hack:

Start **C** from **B** using startActivityForResult.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,C.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

In Activity **C**, create the intent for Activity **D** and set it as a result:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,D.class);
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent)
finish();
```

In Activity **B**, finish and start the intent returned from Activity **C**:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==REQUEST_CODE) {
        finish();
        startActivity(data);
    }
}
```

At this point, both activities **B** and **C** will be finished and the activity stack will be **A => D**

Answer (score 0):

- Start B from A with the Intent flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) to start a new task.
- Start D from C with the Intent flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) to clear the last started task. For backward-compatibility you can use [IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/IntentCompat.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK).

Comment: This would be the solution I was hoping for, but it does not work. After calling finish() in Activity **D** I just end up in Activity **C**.

Answer (score -1):

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP clear your Activity stack , you can use it like codes below :

```
intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks. It was too easy :)

Comment: Was a bit confused at your answer first. But YourActivity is **A** in my case, and called in onBackPressed() in Activity **D**.

Comment: Doing so results in onCreate being called again on activity **A** which I don't want. I want the state it was in to be shown, similar to on how the standard behavior is when clicking Back.